# access html tags and values in jsf context?

Tags: html, jsf, tags

I can access jsf tags in the jsf context, but is there a way to also access regular html tags in the jsf context?

In detail, I have the following on a web page

```
<h:form >
<b>id:</b><b id='idDisplay'>somevalue</b><br/>
```

I would like to access the value of idDisplay in my backing bean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, you'd need to convert them to fullworthy JSF components so that you can grab them by their client ID by [`UIComponent#findComponent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#findComponent%28java.lang.String%29), or to look for a solution in the *right* direction.

As an indirect solution, you could get them as children of a known parent JSF component. In case of Facelets, it'll be an instance of `UIInstructions`. But whatever you plan to do with this, this is a nasty approach as it's pure plain text and you'd need to parse the HTML yourself.

In your future questions, I recommend to just elaborate the functional requirement in detail instead of asking how to achieve a solution of which you thought that it is the right solution, but after all isn't.

Comment: thanks for your comments!  I edited my original post providing more details. If I convert them to JSF components, can the values of these JSF components be altered with the use of Javascript?

Comment: Yes, JSF ultimately just produces HTML/CSS/JS.

Comment: I still don't see how I can return the html tags in the jsf context.  I don't see how I get an instance of UIInstructions

Comment: As answered, get a known parent JSF component and then go through its children.